# How can I use links in Slack which deep link back into my Slack bot?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, slack, slack-api

I have a Slack bot that, in response to a /command - a search query - can display a list of matched database entries. I would like to present this list as a clickable link + short summary for each of the DB entries (using blocks).

Example:

Clicking the link for any entry should tell the Slack bot to display the full database record as a new Slack message.

I can't figure out how to get a link to do anything other than open the browser. None of the options for deep linking, or linking to a bot mention appear to be suitable.

Can anyone think of a solution for this? I would prefer not to give each list entry a button or accessory to 'open' the link.

already tried :

- Each item as an https:// link to the node app behind the bot, passing the title to be displayed. This works but opens a browser window in the interim.
- Mentioning the bot in a link `<@ABOTID>Title to open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only deep link to existing messages, but not use links the same way you can use buttons.

You could of course link directly to your app, but that would always also open the browser, which as you say you don't want.

So for blocks you are left with the option you already mentioned: putting a button next to each entry in the form of a Section with a button.

An alternative would be to use [Secondary Attachments](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments). Those are automatically collapsed for longer text and the user gets a button he can click to expand them.

Comment: thank you. good answer. I hadn't looked at secondary attachments as i'm trying to avoid what are now legacy messaging constructs (even though in some ways they're more useful than blocks) but that is a good alternate solution